# How to iterate through a list variable to fill out an Ansible task's options?

Tags: yaml, ansible

Say I'm starting a Docker Container, and have a list of apps, including port information like so:

```
my_apps:
  - name: App1
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
  - name: App2
    ports:
      - "2001:2001"
```

In the following task, would there be an easy way to extract all the ports from the above variable, for all apps, into the ports option below?

```
- My Docker Container
  docker_container:
   name: ubunty
   image: ubuntu
   ports:
     - "2000:2000" 
     - "2001:2001"
```

Currently, I have another list going for all the ports, but in order to add another port, I have to add it to both lists, which becomes cumbersome. Was hoping there would be another way.

Comment: There is another way, you can use Jinja2, I'm a noob in Jinja2 myself but I know that it can be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
- vars:
  list_of_ports:
    - 2000:2000
    - 2001:2001
```

...and then in your play:

```
- name: App1
    ports: {{ list_of_ports }}
- name: App2
    ports: {{ list_of_ports }}
```

The above may not be perfectly syntactically correct, but it's close enough to give you the idea.

Comment: Each app wouldn't necessarily have all the ports.

Comment: Well then I think you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_fact` to create a new variable and add the ports value to each.  Then use that to call your container.

```
tasks:
  - name: Initialize ports
    set_fact: ports=[]

  - name: Collect ports from apps
    set_fact: ports="{{ports}} + {{item.ports}}"
    with_items: "{{ my_apps }}"
```

Then call your container with the ports variable

```
  - My Docker Container
    docker_container:
    name: ubunty
    image: ubuntu
    ports: "{{ ports }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with jinja filters to reduce your list of apps into a list of ports:

```
my_apps | map(attribute='ports') | list
```

or in your task:

```
- My Docker Container
  docker_container:
    name: ubunty
    image: ubuntu
    ports: "{{ my_apps | map(attribute='ports') | list }}"
```